# Pass attribute from tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, tab

how i can pass attribute from tab? i have this situation:

```
<div id="tabId" class="slds" >
    <lightning:tab label="labelName">
        <c:component1 />
        <c:component1 />
        <c:component1 />
    </lightning:tab>
</div>
```

I want to pass different string attribute at component1. When i realized this, in component, i take the value of attribute with:

```
<aura:attribute name="nameAttributeDeclaredInTab(?)" type="String" />
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: What do you mean by how i can pass attribute from tab???

Comment: component1 is my page with code, i want differenziate the 3 same component  (look at the example) for a string, how can i do this? With attribute? and how can i take the different string whithin the component?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, need this:

```
<c:component1 nameAttribute="value"/>
```

and in the component:

```
<aura:attribute name="nameAttribute" type="String" />
```